# Ubuntu 16.03:IPv6 configurations

Tags: networking, ipv6

I am new in Ubuntu.I need to configure IPv6 in Ubuntu and realize the connectivity between two Ubuntus in two VMwares.
    I have read the Wiki，but just not have a clear idea.
    I think that I should install miredo and set static IPv6 address in both Ubuntus and add a route between the two Ubuntus.Is what I think right?I have tried it but it just doesn't work.
What should I do to realize my goal?What are the steps?
    Thank you a lot!

Comment: Miredo / Teredo are obsolete protocols these days. What information did your network provider give you?

Comment: I have followed a method on the Internet like (http://blog.csdn.net/scylhy/article/details/72699166).But after I restart Ubuntu,there is no 'teredo'.I'm now very helpless.Can you show me the steps or commands to configure IPv6?

Comment: Sorry to give a further description due to the number limits of words.I have installed two Ubuntus,but they are in different computers.They connect to the Internet through the same router,now what I should realize is to enable the communication between the two Ubuntus over IPv6.Thank you very much for your kindness!

Comment: Usually your router will announce which IPv6 addresses are used on your network, and all your machines will auto-configure their own addresses. There is not much you need to do. Unless your ISP/router doesn't provide IPv6. Do you want to connect to the IPv6 internet or just communicate between your two devices?

Comment: Just realize the communication between my two Ubuntus over IPv6.Thank you.